# What is the domain of $1/\sqrt{x^2-4}$ using the set builder notation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm confused when it comes to getting the domain of a function using set builder notation. Please explain also how to do the system of inequalities when getting the domain of the given function:
$$x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$$

Comment: My answer is x:x is an element of all real numbers, 2<x<-2

Comment: So the function is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-4)^2}}$? Or is it $\frac{1}{(\sqrt{x-4})^2}$?

Comment: My mistake. I edited the question now. Please check it.

Comment: I don't see your edit. Was it the first function I wrote, or the second one, or something else?

Comment: It's 1/ sqrt of x^2-4

Comment: {x: 2<x<-2} -> (2, -2)

Comment: @Janine By convention, when using interval notation the bigger number should always go on the right.  I.e. $(2,-2)$ is not correct.  You'd want to put $(-2,2)$.  Not that that's the correct answer (it isn't), I just wanted to help you fix your notation.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the domain of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}$.

We need two things: the denominator must be defined, and nonzero.

The denominator is equal to zero when $x = \pm 2$.

We also have $x^2-4<0$ if $-2<x<2$, so the denominator is not defined for $x \in (-2,2)$. *

Therefore, the function is NOT defined on $x \in [-2,2]$, and thus the function IS defined on $\boxed{\{x \in \mathbb{R}|x<-2~\text{or}~x>2\}}$

Or more simply, $\boxed{\{x \in \mathbb{R}\mid|x|>2\}}$

*Notice that $x^2-4<0 \implies x^2<4 \implies |x|<2$, since $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$.

Then, since $|x|=2$ also makes $f(x)$ undefined, we have f(x) is defined for reals where $|x|>2$.

Comment: Equivalently, $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: |x| >2\}$ in a set builder notation.

Comment: Somebody please fix my LaTeX for my final answer. Thank you

Comment: ugh, i wasn't sure if i could do that, @ChargeShivers

Comment: @SakethMalyala If you just write `|` for the "such that" symbol in set-builder notation, the spacing won't be right (look at your answer and see how everything is crowding the $|$).  Instead it'll look nicer if you use `\mid`.  For instance `$\{x\in\Bbb R \mid |x|>2\}$` gives $\{x\in\Bbb R \mid |x|>2\}$ (see? not so crowded).  **Edit:** Actually I notice that your "or" is pretty crowded as well.  When it comes to `\text` I usually put in an extra space on both sides.  So `a\text{ or } b`, not `a\text{or} b`.  It just makes your equations a little easier to read.

Comment: @SakethMalyala Oh, and $\mapsto$ (which means "maps to") is not the same thing as $\implies$ or $\longrightarrow$ (either of which can be used to mean "implies").  It looks a little weird to say "$x^2-4<0$ *maps to* $x^2<4$".  Just a few little tips to help you out. :-)